# Is there a way to load additional packages specified in the document environment?

Tags: packages, input

It seems strange but I really need this. Is there a built-in macro to load additional packages specified in the document environment?

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```

```
% subfile.tex
\LoadPackage{pstricks}
\LoadPackage{multido}
\pspicture(1,1)
\psframe(1,1)
\endpspicture
```

---

I accepted mbork's answer because it really allow us to load some packages after `\begin{document}`. I have tested the following and it is successfully compiled with a PDF output.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pkgindoc}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```

```
% subfile.tex
\usepackage{xcolor}
I can find a tool to convert PDF to EPS in my neither bathroom nor kitchen.
```

Unfortunately, using pstricks, geometry, hyperref (and among others) do not work. :-(

Comment: See also [packages - Is it possible to usepackage inside an input or include file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395405/is-it-possible-to-usepackage-inside-an-input-or-include-file) • somewhat related: [pdftex - Using DeclareUnicodeCharacter locally (in document, not preamble) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336697/using-declareunicodecharacter-locally-in-document-not-preamble)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now apparently not many people know the following trick.

Make a `pkgindoc.ins` file with the following contents:

```
\input docstrip
\generate{\file{pkgindoc.sty}{\from{ltclass.dtx}{afterpreamble}}}
\endbatchfile
```

in some temporary directory/folder.  Copy the file `ltclass.dtx` to the same directory and run `latex pkgindoc.ins`.  You will obtain a file `pkgindoc.sty`; copy it wherever needed. When you `\usepackage{pkgindoc}`, the commands declared in `ltclass.dtx` as `\@onlypreamble` (like `\usepackage`) will be available *after* `\begin{document}`.

Note: this seemingly won't help if some *package* contains other commands declared as `\@onlypreamble`, e.g. by some other package; but this I know only from experiments, I haven't studied `pkgindoc.sty` (yet;)).

Comment: And what is the problem?

1. You create the file `pkgindoc.ins`.
2. You copy `ltclass.dtx` to the same folder.
3. You run LaTeX on `pkgindoc.ins`.
4. You copy `pkgindoc.sty` to the folder with your document.
5. You `\usepackage{pkgindoc}` and `\usepackage` works after `\begin{document}` (but other things might break).

That's it.

Funny thing is, that this is in LaTeX2e sources, but apparently is not used anywhere.  And there's no description on CTAN, either!

Comment: OK, so I looked at `pkgindoc.sty` and I have to say this is one of the dirtiest tricks I've seen; not really *diffcult* to understand, but just *ugly*.  It is a hack which removes a batch of macros (connected with package writing) between two specified ones from the list to "forbid" after the preamble.  I'm not really sure what this served originally, I'll ask that in a minute;).

Comment: where shoud I use `\usepackage{pkgindoc}`? in `main.tex` or `subfile.tex` (see my question).

Comment: In `main.tex` (more precisely, *before* `\begin{document}`) - it just enables you to use `\usepackage` anywhere.

Comment: There is no need to create `.ins` files. Just run `tex docstrip`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I forgot about this feature.  I'm afraid, however, that it won't work very well in this case, since it seems to generate a file with the same base name as the dtx file.  In other words, you'd have to rename ltclass.sty to pkgindoc.sty afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

The `subpreambles` option of the `standalone` *package* will collect the preambles of included sub-files and read them in the main preamble at the next compiler run. However for this you need a full preamble and `document` environment in the sub-files.

Comment: +1 Does the main file do a test to avoid multiple inclusion of the same package?

Comment: @xport: Yes, this is supported. However, multiple `\usepackage{xxx}` are fine anyway and will only result in the package being loaded once. A more important features is the sorting of package options (enabled using the `sort` option) to avoid package option clashes if two sub-files load the same package with different options. (Of course this also fails if the two options don't mix, but this can't be avoided in an automatic way)

Answer (score 3):

packages can only be loaded  in the preamble part of the document. However, with PSTricks it is a special situation, you can do:

```
% subfile.tex
\input{pstricks}
\input{multido}
\pspicture(1,1)
\psframe(1,1)
\endpspicture
```

Comment: +1 Will it cause a problem if I include many different subfiles and each subfile inputs PSTricks related packages?

Comment: no, _every_ PSTricks package does a test if it is already loaded