# What is pkgindoc.sty really for?

Tags: packages, preamble

During a discussion of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24573/is-there-a-way-to-load-additional-packages-specified-in-the-document-environment/24580), I looked a bit into the `pkgindoc.sty` buried in `ltclass.dtx` (docstrip option `afterpreamble`).  While I understand how this works (and it works in an ugly way IMHO), I am quite curious if anybody knows what  the original purpose of it was (and whether it's documented anywhere)?  (It seems that `pkgindoc.sty` is not generated during normal LaTeX installation, and I've never heard about it from anywhere, including the previous two answers to the above-mentioned question.)

Here is the relevant section from `ltclass.dtx` for reference:

> #### 71   After Preamble
>
> Finally we declare a package that allows all the
>   commands declared above to be `\@onlypreamble` to be used after
>   `\begin{document}`.
>
> ```
> ⟨*afterpreamble⟩
> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
> \ProvidesPackage{pkgindoc}
>          [1994/10/20 v1.1 Package Interface in Document (DPC)]
> \def\reserved@a#1\do\@classoptionslist#2\do\filec@ntents#3\relax{%  
>   \gdef\@preamblecmds{#1#3}}
> \expandafter\reserved@a\@preamblecmds\relax
> ⟨/afterpreamble⟩
> ```

Comment: Instead of showing the (longer) generated file you can just cite section 71 of the LaTeX2e sources.

Comment: You're right, done.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to improve the citation yet more. If you don't like it, please revert it.

Comment: Great, thank you!  I don't know Markdown, so I couldn't do it *that* nice at all":).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used to allow things like `\usepackage` in the document body. This seems to have been used occasionally by members of the LaTeX Project for writing documentation (see for example [this file](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/math/scriptfonts.tex) written by Robin Fairbairns). However, I don't think it's documented anywhere.