# L'esprit de l'escalier / Just Remembered for package/ use \usepackage not in preamble

Tags: packages

Here is the use case: you write a sample document with many demonstrations:  plots and charts, tikz graphics, fancy tables, listing, algorithms, boxes, etc. This gallery display uses many unrelated packages; however they are all `\usepackage`d **together** in the preamble. This makes it difficult to cut and paste your sample document.

Ideally, a new package `escalier` would do it:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{escalier} % will be replaced by many `\usepackage`

 \begin{document}
 \ldots
 \section{TikZ Demo}
 \escalier{tikz}{environments=tikzpicture,commands=\tikz}
 \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
 \tikz

 \section{xcolor}
 \escalier[table]{xcolor}{commands=\rowcolor}
 ... \rowcolor{red}...
 \end{document}
```

Implementation would be two pass: in the first, all commands declared within escalier, are ignored, but register a request to `\usepackage`
in the second run.

**EDIT** 
To make this more specific: I would like to:

1. Be able to write `\usepackage` where it is needed,  **not** in the preamble
2. I think it should be possible to implement this in a two pass compilation. In the first pass all used packages are moved collected.
   Their list is used in the second pass.
3. I notice you would be getting errors in the first run from commands whose package is missing.
4. I propose a new package, which gives a command to silence commands. In the first run, the silenced commands do nothing except for collecting packages. In the second run, these silence commands are activated.
5. I doubt that there is anything in `filecontents` and `standalone` to help in dealing with this challenge: we want one document, but with self adjusting `\usepackage`, not a collection of PDF files created from distinct documents

**Another edit:** : Luckily, an expected and innocent TeXinician would in response throw all his engagements, and make this package per order.

The questions is, as it is usually the case here: what is a cost effective way of addressing the problem and the use case that suggests it. A full package would be nice, but also ideas, directions, etc. For example, an experienced writer could tell on how this was done in some of the TeX books describing packages.

More concretely, a decent answer would be in the form of a simple, low hanging fruit solution an environment that would do most of the stuff 
the package does, but not as nicely is an environment:

```
\begin{escalier}{\usepackage{tikz}\moreCommandsToPreabmle}
   \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}
\end{escalier}
```

(A solution via scripts might be feasible, but in my experience with 
scripts of these sort - they are never robust, and in general, more of a problem on their own right than a solution).

Comment: What is the question?  Would `filecontents` and `standalone` being a viable replacement?

Comment: I will rephrase the question.

Comment: After the edit this still doesn't feel like a question to me, more a request for someone to do a significant amount of work writing a framework to do the job. (Presumably one doesn't need a two-pass TeX run strategy at all: you could use a script to go though the source and find the relevant lines, then to write a temporary file and do a single LaTeX pass on that.)

Comment: Pretty obvious that no one is expected an innocent TeXinician to throw a way all his engagement, and make a package per order. (Most of them are male, aren't they?). The questions is, as it is usually the case: for the most effective way of addressing the problem and the use case: tips, ideas, directions, etc. For example, an experienced writer could tell on how this was done in some of the TeX books describing packages.

Comment: The most effective way (i think) would be to throw away the idea of just *one* document and use `standalone` documents.

Comment: A user expects an example to be simple, not be thrown off by a complicated and unknown syntax. Or is the user expected to learn the syntax of yet another package, that doesn't give him anything? Well, except for just *one* document.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the *package* version of `standalone` (not the `standalone` class) does a lot of what you want. Perhaps you should play with that and see if it does what you want or most of what you want and then revise your question accordingly.

Comment: What to do if, in two different places in the document, a package is loaded with incompatible options? And would it really be better to need(?) to pseudo-load (say) `graphicx` every time you want to use `\includegraphics`? (I ask only for the purpose of clarification.)

Comment: At some extent, at a editor level, LyX solve this (e.g. writing `\implies`  automatically  add`amsmath` in the preamble, if necessary) but only do that  with most usual packages.  With thousands of packages on CTAN with many thousands of own commands, some of them  defined by more than one package, seem unlikely load packages  based on existing **undefined** commands.

Comment: @jon: good point - but, alas, we cannot be much better than the current state of the art. We can try to "add options to package", but there might be issues.

Comment: @Fran: this `\begin{escalier}{\usepackage{tikz}\moreCommandsToPreabmle}
   \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}
\end{escalier}` might work.

Comment: @YossiGil I'm afraid that is swim against the current. LaTeX  only read code sequentially and deliberately disable load packages after the preamble to maintain a logical structure of format and content.  To load a bulk of commands anywhere left `\input{file.tex}`. Seem that there are a [dirty trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24580/11604) to load `.sty` packages in the document, but I afraid that it will left more problems than solutions.

Comment: @Fran: I agree - the current trend is that you include everything at first, and then proceed. This has deep roots: Knuth implementation in Pascal does the same: he has a big initialization module.  Personally, I think this trend is thing of the past, just as monolithic O/S.  It should be obliterated, and the sooner, the better. I do not see any logical structure in a long list of of usepackages that has to be maintained by hand. Most authors have no idea what's in these packages, they just copy it from others and tweak it by hand.

Comment: @YossiGil by "structure" I mean separate as far as possible commands about format  (in the preamble)   of those about  text structure (like `\section` or `\alert` (after the preamble). TeX could be like a Turing-complete programming language, but is to write text, and mainly source code is  text, so I find this still a good idea.  Maybe old, but a monolithic OS is not the best simil, since packages make just the opposite. The problem is just that being modular, load everything is crazy, but only you can decide what packages are essential.

Comment: @Fran: I view this from an SE pov: a lib defines for you which logical commands you have at your disposal, `\node` or `\section`, depending on the library. The global initialization block at the preabmle says ***which*** libs you can included. This info is tightly coupled with  content. Worse: it is tightly coupled with a small bit of the content. I write an article, I use a graph and include the pertinent packages - say one for dealing with gnuplot. I remove the graph - The next day, I add the graph again. 
Change the preamble again? Keep a God list of all packages I might ever use?

Comment: @YossiGil It is one option. Better, you can make your own class that load by default your "essential" packages. Some standard classes already do that (note that with  `beamer` you do not need touch the preamble to add images) While you do not notice excessive compilation times or package conflicts is OK ...  but I personally I prefer be able to deactivate any package at any time with a simple `%`  prefix.